# Is there a rule for what goes between the | x | in a block function?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently studying blocks, and noticed that depending on what's being carried out, the symbol between the 'goalposts' seems to change, is this purely for readability purposes and one could just as easily make every goalpost contain |i|, or is there a rule behind what must go here?

Code examples below.

```
[ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ].each {|i| puts i }


 f = File.open("testfile")
    f.each do |line|
puts line end
f.close
```

Comment: It’s a variable name like any other.

Comment: The goalposts are called pipes.

Answer (score 2):

What you call "symbol between the 'goalposts'" is more commonly called a "parameter" in programming.

A "parameter" is kind of like a "hole" or "placeholder" in the definition of a procedure / function / method / block / subroutine / whatever you want to call it. You can give it any name you want (as long as it is a valid identifier for a parameter, of course). You can use this name inside the body of your procedure / function / method / block / subroutine, without knowing what its exact value at runtime will be.

When you then execute the procedure / function / method / block / subroutine, the caller can pass what is called an "argument", i.e. a specific value to fill this "hole". This "argument" will then be "bound" to the parameter. This means that *for this particular execution* of the procedure / function / method / block / subroutine, when you reference the parameter, it will have this particular value.

So, for example, if you have something like this:

```ruby
def add(first_parameter, second_parameter)
  first_parameter + second_parameter
end

add(23, 42)
```

Then `first_parameter` and `second_parameter` are the *parameters* of the `add` method, and `23` and `42` are the *arguments* passed to this particular execution of `add`.

Similarly, when you have

```ruby
def block_executor
  yield 23, 42
end

block_executor do |first_parameter, second_parameter|
  first_parameter + second_parameter
end
```

Then `first_parameter` and `second_parameter` are the *parameters* of the block, and `23` and `42` are the *arguments* passed to this particular execution of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can name it anything you like as it's the variable name you will be using in the block -- i.e between the `{` & `}`.

But you should name this variable something with meaning to make your code more readable and easier to understand.

In the example above, `num` or `number` would be preferable to `i`.

`line` makes sense because that's how a file is read, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a simple variable, you can name it in the way that best suits you.

But try to name it in a more semantic way, this to help the future you or another developer to improve the reading of your code.

If you look at [here](https://rubystyle.guide/#underscore-unused-vars), you will find some tips for the kind of situations that your asking for.

Here is a style guide provided by Rubocop, which will help you with many of these doubts.

[Rubocop Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide)

Answer (score 0):

The list between the pipe characters (`|...|`) is known as the block parameters and largely follow the same rules as for method parameters and local variables:

- The identifier can contain `_` and alphanumerical characters.
- The identifier may not begin with a number.
- You can use a crazy number of UTF-8 characters like like `Ö`, `¤` or `的`.  For example `π = Math::PI`. If its a good idea is debateable.
- The identifier cannot contain reserved characters like `!, ? +, -, :`.
- You cannot use the same identifier twice in the parameters list.

A block can have any number of positional parameters:

```
... do |a, b, c|

end
```

Unlike with methods and lambdas Ruby doesn't enforce that a block is called with the correct number of arguments.

You can use defaults:

```
def foo
  yield
end

foo do |x = 1|
  x
end
# 1
```

You can use splats to slurp a variable number of arguments and do destructing:

```
def foo(*args)
  yield *args
end    

foo(3, 2, 1) do |*numbers|
  numbers.sort
end
# [1, 2, 3]

foo(3, 1, 5, 8, 2) do |*numbers|
  numbers.sort
end
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]

foo('a', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'f') do |first, *middle, rest|
  middle.sort
end
# ["b", "c", "e"]
```

You can even destructure a single argument:

```
{ bar: [1,2,3], baz: [5, 6, 7, 8] }.map do |key, (first, *middle, last)|
  middle
end
# [[2], [6, 7]]
```

And you can use keyword arguments if there is no logical order to the arguments or if there are so many that you can't keep track of them:

```
def foo
  yield a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, bar: 4, baz: 5
end


foo do |baz:, bar:, optional_parameter: nil|
  bar
end
# 1

foo do |**kwargs|
  kwargs
end
# { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, bar: 4, baz: 5 }
```